# NestJS and Serverless - handler 'handler' is not a function

Tags: typescript, nestjs, serverless-framework, serverless

I am trying to implement NestJS as a AWS Serverless function using serverless-framework.

I was following [this official documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/serverless#example-integration) and my code is exactly as in the documentation. However when I launch it I get the error `Failure: offline: handler 'handler' in [..] is not a function`.

**If I go into my compiled source code of `main.js` and change the line `exports.handler = handler;` to `module.exports.handler = handler;` it starts working.**

I also tried to do change the code in `main.ts` to accommodate this but it does not help since webpack is compiling it differently then.

```
// main.ts
const handler ...;
module.exports.handler = handler;
```

Here is my `main.ts`

```
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Callback, Context, Handler } from 'aws-lambda';
import serverlessExpress from '@vendia/serverless-express';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

let server: Handler;

async function bootstrap(): Promise<Handler> {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
      whitelist: true,
    }),
  );
  await app.init();

  const expressApp = app.getHttpAdapter().getInstance();
  return serverlessExpress({ app: expressApp });
}

export const handler: Handler = async (event: any, context: Context, callback: Callback) => {
  server = server ?? (await bootstrap());
  return server(event, context, callback);
};
```

Here is my `serverless.yml`

```yaml
service:
  name: serverless-example

plugins:
  - serverless-offline

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs12.x

functions:
  main:
    handler: dist/main.handler
    events:
      - http:
          method: ANY
          path: /
      - http:
          method: ANY
          path: '{proxy+}'
```

Here is my webpack.config.js

```js
return {
  ...options,
  externals: [],
  output: {
    ...options.output,
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
  },
  // ... the rest of the configuration
};
```

And lastly here is my tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

Am I missing some config on webpack? Or maybe change in the typescript config files? I have no idea and documentation says that it should just work, however it does not.

Theoretically all I need is it to be `module.exports.handler = handler` instead of `exports.handler = handler` in my compiled file because as I said I did change it and it started to work properly.

This is the interim fix I'm using but obviously this is wrong way of approaching it.

```
"build": "nest build --webpack && sed -i 's/exports.handler = handler;/module.exports.handler = handler;/g' dist/main.js",
```

Comment: since `exports === module.exports` then it should work fine with both, right?

Comment: But it doesn't. :\

Comment: I did a quick test from a brand new project and I'm not experiencing this issue.  What version of Nest are you running?  AFAIK, this is a pretty new feature and might require Nest8

Comment: I am getting the same error. Did you manage to find a fix? @Stan

Comment: Anyone got fix .. using nest8

Comment: same here im using nx workspace with nest8 serverless-plugin-typescript it compiles properly but w/o module.export

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a lot of people are having the same issue and I could not find a "good" solution here is a solution that works: Simply replace the `exports.handler` with `module.exports.handler` in the compiled `main.js` file.

This is how you simply do it using `sed` in your build process inside `package.json`

```
"build": "nest build --webpack && sed -i 's/exports.handler = handler;/module.exports.handler = handler;/g' dist/main.js",
"build:mac": "nest build --webpack && sed -i '' 's~exports.handler = handler;~module.exports.handler = handler;~g' dist/main.js",
```

Note that there is specific command for MacOS since it has a different `sed` implementation for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this by creating ensuring that the webpack output has a `libraryTarget` of `commonjs2`. Create (or edit) a `webpack.config.js` file in the root of the project with the following content ensuring that we set the `libraryTarget` to `commonjs2`:

```js
module.exports = (options) => {
  return {
    ...options,
    output: {
      ...options.output,
      libraryTarget: 'commonjs2',
    },
  };
};
```

In my `serverless.yml` I have the following defined for my lambda function:

```yaml
...

functions:
  example:
    handler: "./dist/apps/example/main.js.handler"
...
```

Please note that `main.js.handler` should be changed if your entrypoint/function is different. For example if it was `entrypoint` this string would be `dist/apps/example/main.js.entrypoint`

Comment: Didn't do anything for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :) for the same problem but with serverless-plugin-typescript with nx workspace

there is all about tsconfig with module: commonjs

```
"compilerOptions": {  
  "module": "commonjs",
},
```

and then I see in ./build folder

```
...
exports.main = main;
```

Comment: it is working solution with `"module": "commonjs",` or one have to remove it ?